# Access "default" linker namespace on android app signed as system

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, dynamic-linking, dlopen

I need to dlopen some system libraries (specifically libgui and libui). I have device vendor key and set "android.uid.system" as android:sharedUserId in manifest. But regular dlopen can only open system libraries listed in /system/etc/public.libraries.txt.
So I dlopen libc.so and use the android_get_exported_namespace function to get the "default" (system) namespace. It works fine on one device, but on others, android_get_exported_namespace returns NULL for the "default" namespace. As far as I understand it is because of namespace.default.visible = false. So my question is, is there a way to get around this limitation and get the system namespace, or maybe I can implement dlopen myself?
Also, if someone can point me to the implementation of android_get_exported_namespace that would be great, because for now I can only find the declaration of this function.
Here is how I obtaining the "default" namespace:

```cpp
#include <dlfcn.h>

typedef struct android_namespace_t* (*android_get_exported_namespace_t)(const char*);

void* getSystemNamespace() {
    dlerror();
    void *lib = dlopen("/system/lib64/libc.so", RTLD_LAZY);
    if (auto err = dlerror()) {
        LOGV("failed to load libc.so, error %s\n", err);
        return NULL;
    }

    dlerror();
    android_get_exported_namespace_t android_get_exported_namespace = (android_get_exported_namespace_t)dlsym(lib, "__loader_android_get_exported_namespace");

    if (!android_get_exported_namespace) {
        LOGV("failed to load function \"android_get_exported_namespace\", error %s\n", dlerror());
        return NULL;
    }

    auto ns = android_get_exported_namespace("default");
    LOGV("namespace: %p", (void*)ns);
    return ns;
}
```